# Alternative to document.body.innerHTML += htmlstring

Tags: javascript

I have a function that does this:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div>lorem ipsum</div>';
```

and it works fine but it breaks my references of other divs (I've read that this is because it parses the body again). Is there a vanilla alternative using only Javascript?

Comment: What does "it breaks my references of other divs" mean?

Comment: For example if I had set `var div = document.querySelector('.example');` after doing the `document.body.innerHTML += '<div>lorem ipsum</div>';
` the variable div would hold a reference to a node that isn't there anymore (it still is but it's outdated) so all event listeners wouldn't work, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I can see

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).app‌​endChild(document.cr‌​eateTextNode('lorem ipsum'))
```

which is just shorthand for

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var text = document.createTextNode('lorem ipsum');
div.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild('div');
```

or

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<div>lorem ipsum</div>');
```

documentation:

- [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [document.createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)
- [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [Element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: which method did you use :p

Comment: Second one, shorter and more elegant IMO!

Comment: Should also consider also [Element.insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) for more flexibility over appendChild()

Answer (score 1):

You can *append* it another div

```js
document.getElementById("demoDiv").innerHTML += '<div>Test 22</div>';
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
<div id="demoDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I wanted to avoid creating a div manually but thanks anyway!